# How to kill process which created by python os.system()

Tags: python, linux, flask

I have a Flask application using python3. Sometimes it create daemon process to run script, then I want to kill daemon when timeout (use `signal.SIGINT`).

However, some processes which created by `os.system` (for example, `os.system('git clone xxx')`) are still running after daemon was killed.
so what should I do? Thanks all!

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using `os.system()` instead of a `subprocess` call which would give you much better control over the subprocesses you create?

Comment: Probably ignorance. `subprocess` is rather more obscure, and there are many examples of using `os.system` still around. Although its documentation says "The subprocess module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results" you only know that if you read the documentation ...

Answer (score 8):

In order to be able to kill a process you need its process id (usually referred to as a pid). `os.system` doesn't give you that, simply returning the value of the subprocess's return code.

The newer `subprocess` module gives you much more control, at the expense of somewhat more complexity. In particular it allows you to wait for the process to finish, with a timeout if required, and gives you access to the subprocess's pid. While I am not an expert in its use, this seems to 
work. Note that this code needs Python 3.3 or better to use the `timeout` argument to the `Popen.wait` call.

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'clone', 'https://github.com/username/reponame'])
try:
    print('Running in process', process.pid)
    process.wait(timeout=10)
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
    print('Timed out - killing', process.pid)
    process.kill()
print("Done")
```

Answer (score 0):

The following command on the command line will show you all the running instances of python.

```
$ ps aux | grep -i python
username  6488   0.0  0.0  2434840    712 s003  R+    1:41PM   0:00.00 python
```

The first number, `6488`, is the PID, process identifier. Look through the output of the command on your machine to find the PID of the process you want to kill.

You can run another command to kill the correct process.

```
$ kill 6488
```

You might need to use `sudo` with this command. Be careful though, you don't want to kill the wrong thing or bad stuff could happen!

Comment: But the subprocess isn't running Python. And how do you distinguish between multiple processes all running the same command line?